# How to create fair lock to solve starvation in java?

Tags: java, concurrency, reentrantlock

I want to create fair lock so that each thread was given a lock one after the other regardless of priorities.

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class StarvationRunnable implements Runnable {

    private ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock(true);

    public void doLongTask() {
        lock.lock();
        // to imitate long running task in critical section
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
            ;
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is running with priority "
                + Thread.currentThread().getPriority() + " !");
        lock.unlock();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (;;) {
            doLongTask();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StarvationRunnable runnable = new StarvationRunnable();

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
            thread.setPriority(i == 3 ? Thread.MIN_PRIORITY : Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
            thread.start();
        }
    }
}
```

So I have 4 threads. 3 with max priority and 1 with min priority. I create fair lock by

```
new ReentrantLock(true);
```

When I run this demo it doesn't give thread with min priority to execute as many times as to threads with max priority. But I think that fair lock is just for that.

How to use fair lock correctly?

Comment: It means that each thread is given a lock sequentially so that each thread can run synchronized method the same amount of times.

Comment: @Volodia: Well that's not how the documentation defines fairness: "When set true, under contention, locks favor granting access to the longest-waiting thread."

Comment: wouldn't the JIT optimize out such a loop  ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Fairness has nothing to do with thread priorities. [The javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) says:

> The constructor for this class accepts an optional fairness parameter. When set true, under contention, locks favor granting access to the longest-waiting thread.

On the other hand, thread priorities are hints to the native thread scheduler in order to give more CPU time to high-priority threads than for low-priority threads if they are competing to get CPU time.

Comment: When I run demo, threads with less priorities are not given lock as much as threads with high priority. But docs say `granting access to the longest-waiting thread`

Comment: Why fair lock doesn't give lock to thread with min priotity as many times as to thread with max priority?

Comment: Because it does what the documentation says it does: give the lock to the longest waiting thread. Since threads with highest priority have more access to the CPU than threads with lowest priority, there is a bigger chance for a thread with high priority to actually execute the instructions asking for the lock. For example, highest-priority threads could be scheduled 100 times and run the long task 100 times before the min priority thread is scheduled and thus has a chance to ask for the lock.

Comment: Also, note that your loop has a good chance of being completely eliminated by the JIT, which is smart enough to detect code doing nothing and optimize it away.

Comment: Thanks! Don't you know the way to code starvation in simple demo without using priorities?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a sample implementation using java `wait()` and `notify()` framework. Which provides the lock based on first come first serve (FCFS) basis irrespective of thread priority.

You can have a look at the Fair lock implementation at https://github.com/nenapu/JavaLocks